# How to access database without having to start server

Tags: database, apache, xampp

in the past i have made a project using xampp with database and all. Now I have decided i want to use vagrant as a web server but i still need some files from the old xampp server. I tried starting xampp today but for some reason its not willing to start. I get the error below:

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 12:19:41  [Apache]   This may be
>   due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  12:19:41  [Apache]
>     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   12:19:41  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   12:19:41  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 12:19:41 
>   [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this 12:19:41  [Apache]
>     entire log window on the forums

Is there a way i can export my old database without having to start xampp?

Comment: Why don't you simply solve whatever issue it is that prevents to start the daemons?

Comment: You _could_ copy the data folder of the mysql server, but you'd need to import them into another server and launch that to be able to make sense of the data, so no improvement.